# Linking models created using Devise + Activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin, has-one

I have two models Listing and Profile configured with Active Admin. The model Profile is generated using devise. I have established a has one relationship between them. I want to create a system in which for each new listing, a profile is automatically created and linked. (Imagine airbnb in which a seller can have only one listing and cannot rent) This linking should be both valid in activeadmin and also when a user logins to my app. How should I approach this.

Side note: My model Profile is not registerable. So using it through activeadmin is important so that once listing and profile are created by the superuser, I can send the login details to the person and they can login to view their listing.

PS: Rails Newbie Here! So easier methods,tutorials or directions will be truly appreciated and if you are in or near London thanked by a beer.

Answer (score 0):

For the has_one relationship please see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association

If you want to create a Profile when creating a Listing, you can do it with the ActiveAdmin's create controller of Listing:

The code should be something like this: (put it in app/admin/listing.rb)

```
controller do
  def create
    # Create the profile.
    @profile = Profile.new
    # Create the listing and connect the profile to it.
    @listing = Listing.create(permitted_params[:name])
    @listing.profile = @profile

    create! do |success, failure|
      succes.html { redirect_to admin_dashboard_path}  # Or whatever path.
    end
  end
end
```